# tf return Invalid JPEG data, size 1100

Tags: python, tensorflow, jpeg

I am new in tensor flow and I am trying to feed jpg images to tensorflow but  return an error.

This is the code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(['D-MAIZ-BUENO/lista'])   

reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)

my_img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(value,channels=0) # jpg decoder 


init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()

with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(init_op)



  coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
  threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

 for i in range(50): #length of your filename list
  image = my_img.eval() #here is your image Tensor :) 

#    print(image.shape)
#    Image.show(Image.fromarray(np.asarray(image)))
#
#  coord.request_stop()
#  coord.join(threads)
```

the images are in D-MAIZ-BUENO/lista
and the lista is a list with the jpg images.
The images are jpg 640x480 pixels size 24.2kb

The error is:

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors.InvalidArgumentError: Invalid JPEG     data, size 1100
>        [[Node: DecodeJpeg = DecodeJpegacceptable_fraction=1, channels=0, fancy_upscaling=true, ratio=1, try_recover_truncated=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]]
>   Caused by op 'DecodeJpeg', defined at:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to feed the list of filenames to the queue. So, for instance,

```
with open('D-MAIZ-BUENO/lista', 'r') as f:
  filename_list = f.read().splitlines()
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filename_list)
```

Comment: Thanks it only produce an error because the directory is no attached to filename